# Android using Fragment without extend the class

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a pretty straightfoward question... i would like to use very simple fragments and tell them which layout to inflate without the need to create a class for each fragment and override the method `onCreateView`

in simple words i would like to do:

```
Fragment f = new Fragment();
            f.loadfromlayout(R.layout.layout);
```

is there any way to achieve that?

the closest i get is:

```
new Fragment() {
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_send_screenshot_step1, container, false);
                                }
                            }
```

======================UPDATE===================

Just to clarify a bit more my requirements. What i'm trying to achieve is this:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_screenslide.mp4

Use ViewPager to create a step-by-step wizard
as shown in the official android documentation my example will load a very simple layout for each "step" (every step is a fragment)... and in order to get this using the default android components i need to create a new class extending `Fragment` for every single step in my wizard all of them are exaclty the same thing just specifying a different layout in the `onCreateView`

that is very unnelegant and a lot of repetitive code in my opinion. i would like to avoid

Comment: `FragmentManager` uses reflection to reinstate your fragments after configuration change, what you're trying to accomplish won't work without custom fragment class.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the goal of a fragments. Why do you want to use it like that?

Comment: This won't work. After process death, you'll get a NoClassDefFoundError error in production.

Comment: BTW, repetition is less of a problem than coupling between components that should be independent. Elegance might not match maintainability. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, since this fragment is designed to be used only in this class and in this component i dont see it as "coupling between components"... android architecture demands a lot of repetition as many classes need to be created for single use components due the lack of flexibility

Answer (score 1):

As many people pointed in the comments this behavior was not originally desinged to happen in android.

I found a solution that will work for my case and still fine.

```
public class GenericFragment extends Fragment {

    public static GenericFragment newInstance(@LayoutRes int layout) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("layout", layout);

        GenericFragment g = new GenericFragment();
        g.setArguments(b);
        return g;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt("layout"), container, false);
    }
}
```

this way i need only 1 single class extending `Fragment` and i can have as many pages with different layouts i want in my wizards... as long as the pages dont have "specific behavior"